# looping on list to display positioned behind each other

Tags: dart, flutter

i have a list and am looping on it and display a positioned container for each item .. and they are behind each other ..

am doing this:

```
     List<Widget> createQues(){
data = questionsList;
double bottom = 190.0;
List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
for (var q in data){
  bottom += 10.0;
  children.add(new Positioned(
      bottom: bottom,
      child: new Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 80.0,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(20.0)),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            new BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xffECECEC),
              blurRadius: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: new Text(q.title),
      )
  )
  );
}
return children;
}
```

and then called it like this:

```
 new Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
    children: createQues() 
    )
```

my problem is that the first item in my list is actully displayed the last in the stack .. i want the first item in the list to be on the top of the stack and the others sorted behind it ..

for example:

lets say i have 2 elements in the list :

[image]

as shown i will always got item 2 on top of item 1.. how to make it sorted so item 1, item 2, item 3 ... not the reverse on the stack?

Comment: @pskink no i did not

Comment: @pskink i just did .. and i already know what does bottom do .. my problem is not with the position .. my problem is that the first item in the list is actually displayed the last .. and the last item in the list is the one on the top

Comment: @pskink the first was 190.0 and the second is 200.0

Comment: @pskink i don't know if we are talking about the same bottom .. or i misunderstood you

Comment: @pskink and how to use it?

Comment: @pskink i think my question wasn't clear .. i just edited it .. if you please can check it .. i don't have any problem with positioning the containers .. my problem is the sorting of the children in the stack

Comment: @pskink any news?

Comment: @pskink no actually when i reversed the list .. that all what i wanted .. the first item was on the top

Comment: @pskink yes true it will not change the position .. and i didn't ever want to change the position .. all i wanted is to sort the displayed items ..  that's all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just reverse the questions list before using it?
Like, you could try changing `data = questionsList` to `data = questionsList.reversed`.